# Set CloudWatch alarms on "AWS/OpsWorks" metrics in Cloudformation Template store in "eu-west-1"

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-opsworks, cloudwatch-alarms, aws-regions

I'm building a Cloudformation Template that deploys an infrastructure on the region "eu-west-1". This region is "global" in OpsWorks. It means that all the associated metrics for this resource ("AWS/OpsWorks") are stored in the region "us-east-1".

I want to create some alarms on those metrics, but it's impossible because the alarms created are stored in the same region than my Cloudformation, and do not have access to the metrics stored in the global region "us-east-1". So all my alarms are in state "Insufficient data" because the metrics do not exist in this region.

Does someone have a workaround to solve this issue?